# Cloudwatch alarm triggers too often

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, cloudwatch-alarms

**Summary:** We are using a Cloudwatch alarm to tell us when a certain (EMR) cluster is having trouble getting (spot) instances. The alarm is triggering more often than it should. Why?

**Detail:** In theory, it is set to aggregate for a period of 1 hr, and only go to alarm if 12 datapoints alarm out of 12 evaluation periods.

In practice, we received ~16 messages last night at very consistent time intervals: ALARM at 36 min past the hour, and OK at 51 min past the hour.

1. **How is it possible that the alarm could switch between OK-> ALARM every hour?** Wouldn't a single "ok" datapoint cause alarms to be ok for the next 12 hours? (in practice, the alarm has cycled from ALARM->OK->ALARM every hour for eight hours in a row)
2. What can we change to make this alarm better reflect the intended behavior? So far, increasing the `evaluation_periods` has not made the problem go away.

[image: Sample alarm configuration]